# How Read Access Database Date Time Format as Date Only

Tags: c#

I have used like this,

```
DateTime dueDate;
DateTime.TryParse(dataRead["Date required"].ToString(), out dueDate);
list.add(new list {  DueDate = dueDate.ToShortDateString() });
```

I have also tried like this,

```
 DateTime dueDate;
 DateTime.TryParse(dataRead["Date required"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), out dueDate);
 list.add(new list {  DueDate = dueDate.ToShortDateString() });
```

but it is not reflected. I also changed in access database format as Short date, but that is also not gave correct answer.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Keep in mind, that the `DateTime` structure is basically an `Int64` counting ticks since `DateTime.MinValue`. So you'll never have "just" the date. What you *can* get with `dateTimeVariable.Date` is a `DateTime` where the time "component" is set to all zeros. (Again, there is no "real" date component and time component. Those are infered from the number of ticks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dueDate.Date`

[DateTime.Date Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the date component of this instance.

---

**Example**

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 6, 1, 7, 47, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString());

// Get date-only portion of date, without its time.
DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;

// Display date using short date string.
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("d"));

// Display date using 24-hour clock.
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("g"));
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
```

**Results**

```
// The example displays output like the following output:
//       6/1/2008 7:47:00 AM
//       6/1/2008
//       6/1/2008 12:00 AM
//
```

---

[**You can play with a demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h1rAZD)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
DateTime dueDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date required"].ToString());

DateTime dueDate= dueDateTime.Date;
```

First Convert it into Stting and then to DateTime
and then get Date **from** DateTime